# How to enable newline seperate when run command `ls -l` when stdout is not a terminal

Tags: shell, command-substitution

I store the command in a variable `cmd`, and get the output of the command using this statement:

```
echo `$cmd`
```

everything works fine except `ls -l`, the newline is missing.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Thank you, I tried, but it didn't work. However, I found a solution, using `sh -c "$cmd"`

Comment: Oh. Is `echo "$(cmd)"` what you wanted? You could just use `$cmd` instead.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, just use `$cmd` is weired, like a variable declaration, but it also works.

Comment: @Divlaker, the context of what you are trying to accomplish with the output of the command may be helpful as well. You need to understand the relationship with echo and $IFS. In your example `echo` sees all the output as if it was just one long line of arguments as in `echo arg1 arg2 arg3 ... argn`. Another way to show this is to do the following. Execute `seq -w 1 10`. Then execute `echo $(seq -w 1 10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've stored a command in a string variable, then to run it you need

```
eval "$cmd"
```

Running `$cmd` only works if the command doesn't contain any shell special characters other than whitespace. Storing a command in a string variable is a bad idea in general. It would be better to define a function:

```
cmd () {
  ls -l
}
```

Then you can run it with just `cmd`.

Your most immediate problem is that you further mangle the output of the command, because you're using an unquoted command substitution. You need to use double quotes around variable and command substitutions. With `cmd` defined as a function:

```
echo "`cmd`"
```

To avoid surprises with complex commands, use dollar-parenthesis instead of backticks:

```
echo "$(cmd)"
```

See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for explanations.

Comment: Thank you. I tried `cmd='cd / && ls -l'`, `eval "$cmd"`works and plain `$cmd` not work.